# Get where user saved file with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the physical path with Javascript (or any other library) where the user saved the file he/she downloaded from my Web Application?

Comment: No, this isn't possible.

Comment: there is no way of doing that

Answer (score 0):

No, having such a feature would be a security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Only Google Chrome support the filesystem-API, but i'm not sure if a website can use this Api.

[More informations.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Answer (score 0):

No, unless he/she tells you where they saved it, or unless you control the user of the application's​ computer. This is a silly question if you think about it logically, do you not think there might be few very major security concerns if you were able to very easily spy on the internals of users computers?